# Not able to submit python application using spark submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I generated an `.egg` file. Now I want to run my Spark application using `spark-submit` command on my local Windows. I have Spark version 2.1.1

```
spark-submit --py-files  local:///C:/git_local/sparkETL/dist/sparkETL-0.1-py3.6.egg driver.py

spark-submit --py-files  local:///C:/git_local/sparkETL/dist/sparkETL-0.1-py3.6.egg driver.py
```

This is code I'm trying but I'm getting error:

```
File not found(c:\spark\bin\driver.py)
```

Why `spark-submit` is trying to find file on local path when I already packaged it inside `.egg`? I read `.egg` files are similar to `jar`, so I assume like in case of `jar` file we pass class name to run `spark-submit`. Now I'm passing driver.py which is main file but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark-submit in this case pyspark always requires a python file to run (specifically driver.py), py-files are only libraries you want to attach to your spark job and are possibly used inside driver.py.

If you want to make it works, make sure driver.py exists in current location which you trigger spark-submit. Or change it to something like  local:///C:/git_local/sparkETL/driver.py

Comment: Ok Thanks for your response if i copy driver.py file to bin directory i'm getting module not found error . Module util is custom module which i have created and is inside egg. why it is not able to locate that any thoughts?

Comment: If you can run driver.py spark job it works correctly. The problem is now with you egg package, please double check it to see whether you created the correct egg file

Comment: Some how module util was not included in dependencies regenerated .egg now it is able to read all modules, but now spark session is not getti'ng intialized while submitting .egg to spark submit command. And if i don't use spark submit and run it directly from pycharm IDE it is running fine. Any idea what i'm missing while packaging this is first time i'm trying to do this

Comment: Please add your project structure and setup.py, I will take a look at them

Comment: https://github.com/rohitdogra99/sparkETL/tree/spark-add-tgt-sink please chk this github link. for folder structure and setup.py and please advise what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Seem nothing wrong with your package, please update more log to understand it more. btw change `local:///C:/git_local/sparkETL/dist/sparkETL-0.1-py3.6.egg` to `file:///C:/git_local/sparkETL/dist/sparkETL-0.1-py3.6.egg` and test again

Comment: changed from local to file and now it is working fine Thankyou :)

Comment: As of now it worked by changing from local to file , suppose in future if i want to run python APP on some cluster then i need to use local or file ? As my egg file will be present on local and if i use file it will try to find  on cluster not on my machine how to handle this scenario

Comment: It depends on how you run your Spark cluster, if you are using Amazon EMR, all file should be on S3, on GCP Dataproc you can upload file to GCS. If you use your own Spark Cluster with HDFS, files are stored in HDFS. To run with small Spark cluster file:// should work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196127/discussion-between-rohit-and-duy-nguyen-hoang).